# Plotting in maple

Tags: maple

I'm having trouble plotting a set of complex numbers in maple.

I know what it should look like from a drawing I produced but I'd like to plot it in maple. My code is as follows;

```
z := x + I*y;

plots:-implicitplot([abs(z) <= 2, abs(z) >= 1, abs(arg(z)) >= Pi/4,
                     abs(arg(z)) <= Pi/2], x = -3...3, y = -3...3, filled = true);
```

The issue is that the inequalities are being plotted independently of each other rather than all together, so even the first pair of inequalities together fill the entire plane. Is there any way I can have the $4$ conditions imposed in $S$ be taken into account at the same time, rather than separately?

Answer (score 4):

Didn't you mean for the second inequality to be reversed? Otherwise the first is redundant.

The command that you need is **inequal**, not **implicitplot**. Your **arg**s should be **argument**s. Your *z* expressions should be wrapped in **evalc**. (I don't why that's necessary, but it seems to be.) There's no need for **filled= true**. So, the command is

```
plots:-inequal(
     [evalc(abs(z)) <= 2, evalc(abs(z)) >= 1, 
      evalc(abs(argument(z))) >= Pi/4, evalc(abs(argument(z))) <= Pi/2
     ], x = -3...3, y = -3...3
 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes using `plots:-inequal` takes a long time, in those cases I just use `plots:-implicitplot` with `filledregions = true` option. But I don't use a list of inequalities as its argument. For one plot only, `implicitplot` needs one equation/inequality, so what function can you use that gives you the intersection of regions for your inequalities? Very simple, just define a binary piecewise function with `piecewise` command. Here is how I do your plot.

```
f := piecewise( And( abs( x + y*I ) <= 2, abs( x + y*I ) >= 1, abs( argument( x + y*I ) ) >= Pi/4, abs( argument( x + y*I ) ) <= Pi/2 ), 1, 0 );
plots:-implicitplot( f > 1/2, x = -3..3, y = -3..3, filledregions = true, coloring = [yellow, white], view = [-3..3, -3..3] );
```

The output plot is the following.
[image]

Note that `plots:-inequal` gives a more accurate output, but `plots:-implicitplot` takes less time, so you should consider the trade-off between them and see which is better on your specific example.